# Linked XSL Content Doesn't refresh in DVWP

Tags: list-form

I've implemented Stefan Bauer's awesome post on customizing list forms here: http://www.n8d.at/blog/make-custom-list-forms-centralized-manageable/

This essentially shows how to separate the XSL from the DVWP to allow easy updating of form layout. I love it and it's working on my custom List forms for Edit and New.

HOWEVER, for the DISPLAY form the XSL isn't updating after the first iteration of customizations. It sees the initial customizations, but no updates thereafter. I've cleared cache and ensured that the XSL file is publishing to a major version and have eliminated customizations to ensure that it wasn't something I did.

I'm using SP Designer 2013.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Josh

Comment: Can you try checking-out then checking-in (publish major version) your XSL if it is available?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was a cache issue or just SharePoint floopy-ness but it seems to be working again. Just inconsistent. Here's praying it gets consistent!

Thanks anyway!
Josh